# Program memory question (working dispite insufficient memory)

Tags: pic, c, lcd

I am writing this program to a Microchip PIC.

```
 char * we_are_display = "hello";
 char ahimouz[2];
 sprintf(ahimouz,"%s %s",we_are_display,"5");
 WriteStringToLCD(ahimouz);
```

This program works despite the memory allocated to array `ahimouz` is only 2 bytes. Why is that so?

[image]

Comment: I think this is a programming question and hence it is off-topic.

Comment: I would change `char ahimouz[2]` to `char *ahimouz`, try this.

Comment: Dear Makouda, the message you got from StackOverflow might mean that [you've asked too many low quality questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) and the site has blocked your account because of that. So, it has nothing to do with this question being on-topic there or here. You have already asked [a question that has 5 downvotes here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/113440/29792). If you're not careful with the quality of your questions, you won't be able to ask questions here, too.

Comment: The question ban doesn't transfer from SO to this site. Moreover, I don't see anything wrong with this question: embedded programming is on topic.

Comment: @Electropepper - your comment is just plain wrong! Instead of an insufficiently sized array that the OP is using, you are instead proposing writing through an _uninitialized_ pointer. You haven't allocated any memory to receive the output of sprintf!

Comment: It may not be forbidden here, but there is really nothing embedded-*specific* about it, and it's attracting more than its fair share of utterly incorrect responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example you're not out of memory, you simply haven't allocated enough memory to hold the string. The remainder will end up in a memory area that's available to the processor but the compiler isn't aware of. While it may not cause a problem with this simple example in practice it can overwrite other variables and memory areas and should be avoided.

Also as Majenko mentioned in a comment you may want to take a look at `snprintf` which is a safer version to use because it also includes a parameter to specify the buffer length. Not all PIC compilers support it but if your one does the syntax would be:

```
snprintf(ahimouz, sizeof(ahimouz), "%s %s", we_are_display, "5");
```

That would prevent the possibility of other memory areas being overwritten, although it would also only display `h` because your buffer size is only large enough to hold a single character plus the null terminator.

Comment: You may want to expand the answer to mention that snprintf() is preferred over sprintf() to prevent these kind of buffer overruns.

Comment: @Majenko, good point, not sure that Microchip C8 supports it but no doubt others would.